# Keras ValueError: No data provided for "add". Need data for each key in: ['add'] using Model API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I would like to use Keras for binary classification. Below is my code:

```
input1 = tf.keras.Input(batch_size=batch_size, shape=(len1,))
output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(input1)
input2 = tf.keras.Input(batch_size=batch_size, shape=(len2,))
output2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(input2)
inputs = [input1, input2]
outputs = [output1, output2]
logits = tf.keras.layers.Add()(outputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

This would give me error `ValueError: No data provided for "add". Need data for each key in: ['add']`

I tried `logits = tf.keras.layers.add(outputs)`, this would give the same error.

But if after `logits = tf.keras.layers.Add()(outputs)` I use:

```
probs = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(logits)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=probs)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())
```

It will work. I'm using tensorflow 2.0

What's happening here?

Comment: Works okay to me. Version 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm using tf.dataset here. It turns out I need to specify the correct input and output names for the tensors as tf.dataset is looking for these names while feeding the data to keras.

so `input1` and `input2` should have the corresponding name of the input features, and since the label is named `label`, it should be `logits = tf.keras.layers.Add(name="label")(outputs)`